# how to remove item from lIst view

Tags: android

I am using the code given in below link

http://jsharkey.org/blog/2008/08/18/separating-lists-with-headers-in-android-09/

Please help me how to delete an item from list view

Comment: Just remove the item at perticular position in your `ArrayList` and call the method `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove items from the Adapter and call notifyDataSetChanged() . it should refresh the content of your listview.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            final TableRow row = this.rows.get(position);
ImageButton imgButton = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        imgButton.setTag(row);




@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ImageButton button = (ImageButton) v;
        TableRow row = (TableRow) button.getTag();

        tableRowAdapter.deleteRow(row);
        tableRowAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
```